# select particular column in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have a dataset called "file01" which consist of many variables.
I want to select just a few variables for my further analysis.

I have used the "select" function from dplyr library

```
> file02 <- select(file01, Date, State, Market Center, Modal Price)
Error: unexpected symbol in "file02 <- select(file01, Date, State, Market Center"
```

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are spaces in your column names. quote the names with backtick ` to escape them. or use `select_`

Comment: Thank you. This works! It was probably because of spaces in my column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample dataset

```
df <- data.frame(school = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
        students = c(round(runif(6, 1, 10), 0)),
        grade = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))

school students grade
1      A       10     1
2      B        8     1
3      A        8     2
4      B        3     2
5      A        8     3
6      B       10     3
```

Now i want to select only school and students

```
df[,c("school","students")]

 school students
1      A       10
2      B        8
3      A        8
4      B        3
5      A        8
6      B       10
```